I have a valid 10 year USA visa. But been to Iran and Syria. Can I visit US now?
I have a valid 10 year US visitor visa, but never been to US till date. In the mean time, I had visited Syria and Iran for tourism purpose. Will I be able to enter USA now?

See Does travel to Iran void an existing visa. Not posting as a duplicate because I’m unsure if the answer from 2019 is still correct.

@Traveller Yup, still current!
